# find elements having custom attribute with some specific value and replace it

Tags: jquery, html

I want to find all element which has attribute `data-socketid` with value `abc` and replace the value with `xyz`. How to do this.

> please note that abc and xyz both are dynamically created when page
>   refreshed

This is what I have done so far. But its not working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="chat-win" data-socketid="abc">
   <div class="close-conversation-box">                   
      <div class="text-right">                     
        <a id="end-chat" data-socketid="abc" >End Chat</a>
        <a id="stop_bot"  data-socketid="abc" >Stop Bot</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var matchDataSocketId = $("[data-socketid$=abc]");
var len = Object.keys(matchDataSocketId).length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   $(matchDataSocketId[i]).attr('data-socketid', $(matchDataSocketId[i]).attr('data-socketid').replace(abc, xyz));
}
```

Any help, suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your HTML example implies that the `abc` and `xyz` are the entire value, yet your JS implies that it's a partial match/replacement that you're trying to do. As the logic for either situation is *very* different could you please give a concrete example of your situation

Comment: Actually at the point of time i want to change the entire value but some time i need to replace a part of the value. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In which case @Satpal has you covered

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan what to do if i want to replace the entire value?

Comment: Satpal's answer works for both situations

Comment: yes I have check this. its working. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the code sampleimplies that it's a partial match/replacement, You can use [`.attr(fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) to update the attribute value

```
$("[data-socketid=$abc]").attr(function(_, value) {
   return value.replace('abc', 'xyz');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("[data-socketid=abc]").attr("data-socketid", "xyz");
```

It simply iterates through matching elements, and changes the value of `data-socketid` attribute to `xyz`.

Please note that I've removed `$` before `=` in your selector since you've mentioned that the matching elements should have `abc` as the value of their `data-socketid` attribute.

Comment: Just FYI you don't need each: `$("[data-socketid=abc]").attr("data-socketid", "xyz");`. *However* I think the OP needs to do partial match/replacement.